# Converting Java classes to Android

Tags: java, android, netbeans

Can I convert my Java classes easily for Android, or should I write them from scratch?

I'm writing a few Java classes in MVC style, to create a desktop version. At some point I'd like to transfer them to Android. I sure would appreciate some tips on this (I'm using Netbeans).

Comment: It all depends on how you've written them. Otherwise I fear that this question may be a bit too broad to be easily or succinctly answered.

Comment: Android classes *are* Java, but you'll have to work within the Android framework for view classes - ie, you can't just instantiate a `JFrame` and start adding things to it; Android classes typically extend specific parts of the framework, like `Activity`, `View`, etc. If you're unfamiliar with Android apps, I'd recommend [starting at the source](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html).

Comment: I'm fishing for design tips to keep in mynd while developing. I have all db methods separate for SQLite and all GUI stuff separate.

Comment: If you have followed MVC strictly, you would need to change the code at Controller and View layers.

Comment: @GV: has hit the nail on the head. If written well with good separation of MVC concerns, with classes that have high cohesion and low coupling, you should be able to re-use parts of your model for both Android and desk-top.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help but Netbeans has a plug-in available to make Android apps. Check out: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/19545/nbandroid